# kable_styling for alternative row colors in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, latex, r-markdown

I'm trying to use `kable` and `kableExtra` to generate a table in `latex` document at `Rmarkdown`.

I have used the xcolor package in the header of .Rmd file :

```
header-includes: 
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

but when I use  `latex_options = "striped"` in `kable_styling`

I'm getting the error :

```
knitr::kable(cbind(main()$AEP),format = "latex",booktabs = T)%>%
kable_styling(latex_options="striped",position = "center",full_width = F)

Warning: running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS report.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output report.pdf --template "C:\Users\ali.hadjihosseini\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43
Warning: Error in : pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Stack trace (innermost first):
    53: pandoc_convert
    52: convert
    51: render
    50: download$func [C:\Users\ali\Desktop\dashbord\/server.R#1164]
     1: runApp
Error : pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

If I don't use that `latex_options="striped"`, everything is fine !
Can anybody tell me what is wrong here ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. For me this works even without `\usepackage{xcolor}`. You should provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: [https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf] here is saying I have to use `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`, what is the difference between this one and `\usepackage{xcolor}` ?

Comment: `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` is included by default, so you don't need `\usepackage{xcolor}`